# Convert System.Drawing.Image to Emgu.CV.Image<Gray,byte>

Tags: c#, image, emgucv, typeconverter

Is there any way  to convert an Image of type System.Drawing.Image in to Image of Emgu.CV.Image type or vice versa on EmguCV using C#? I will explain per your request if additional explanation is needed about the purpose of doing this.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
// Converting the master image to a bitmap
Bitmap masterImage = (Bitmap) pbxMaster.Image;

// Normalizing it to grayscale
Image<Gray, Byte> normalizedMasterImage = new Image<Gray, Byte>(masterImage);
```

Comment: I have seen this answer everywhere, but it does not work. I'm using Emgu.CV 4.6. Image<Gray, byte> will not accept a bitmap.

Answer (score 5):

EmguCV version 4.2.0.3636 [and forward] works with below code:

```
using System.Drawing;
using System.Drawing.Imaging;
using Emgu.CV;
using Emgu.CV.Structure;

//inputImage type is System.Drawing.Image
Bitmap bitmapImage = new Bitmap(pictureBox1.Image);

Rectangle rectangle = new Rectangle(0, 0, bitmapImage.Width, bitmapImage.Height);//System.Drawing
BitmapData bmpData = bitmapImage.LockBits(rectangle, ImageLockMode.ReadWrite, bitmapImage.PixelFormat);//System.Drawing.Imaging

Image<Bgr, byte> outputImage = new Image<Bgr, byte>(bitmapImage.Width, bitmapImage.Height, bmpData.Stride, bmpData.Scan0);//(IntPtr)
//outputImage type is Emgu.CV.Image
```

Comment: Remember to check bitmap locks if you are trying to display the images as well.
https://weblogs.asp.net/anasghanem/solving-quot-a-generic-error-occurred-in-gdi-quot-exception

Comment: Why not use `bmpdata.Stride`? The calculation of Width*4 or Width*3 may be off by some pixels, because internally, data must be aligned to a multiple of 8 or so.

Comment: @Thomas Weller Edited my answer to reflect true value of 'strid'. thanks.